# Can we have more than one app catalog in a single tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can we have more app catalog in a single tenant. If yes, please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You cant have more than 1 app catalog in one tenant, in your situation what i think.

- You should go to multi tenant environment, one for Dev, one for QA
  and one for Production. once your testing complete then you can
  deploy your app in Prod Tenant.
- Other is solution dont install the app in prod but it has some risk.
  If users have permission and they see it and install without
  informing anybody.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recently introduced feature, called a [site collection app catalogs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog) that allows you to do this.

[image: Diagram illustrating the concept of site collection app catalog]